# Does PromiseKit have an RxSwift Zip alternative?

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift, promisekit

I am currently working a project with a requirement to refactor the `RxSwift` dependencies for introduce `PromiseKit`.

I am not hugely familiar with `RxSwift` or `PromiseKit` so please forgive me if this is an obvious one.

I am looking for a way to handle the Zip use case still

```
override func start() -> Observable<CoordinationResult> {

    let tabBarController = UITabBarController()
    let tabs: [SectionTab] = [.feed]
    let coordinationResults = Observable.from(configure(tabBarController: tabBarController, withTabs: tabs)).merge()

    window.rootViewController = tabBarController
    window.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return coordinationResults
        .take(1)
}

private func configure(tabBarController: UITabBarController, withTabs tabs: [SectionTab]) -> [Observable<Void>] {
    let navControllers = tabs
        .map { tab -> UINavigationController in
            let navController = BaseNavigationController()
            navController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: tab.title, image: nil, selectedImage: nil)
            return navController
    }

    tabBarController.viewControllers = navControllers
    tabBarController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white // Fix dark shadow in nav bar on segue

    return zip(tabs, navControllers)
        .map { (tab, navController) in
            switch tab {
            case .feed:
                let coordinator = FeedCoordinator(navigationController: navController, dependencies: dependencies)
                return coordinate(to: coordinator)
            }
    }
}
```

From what I understand, `Zip` combines 2 Observables and allows you to action on them, emitting a single observable, which is essentially the result of the 2 original observables and your action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all your snippet of code includes Apple's Swift `zip` which has nothing to do with reactive programming nor `RxSwift`.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1541125-zip

In your case it simply combines two arrays `tabs` and `navControllers` pair wise.

Your understanding of reactive `Zip` operator kinda oversimplifies more complicated cases for zipping streams with more than one emitted value.
When in doubt always check the marbles diagram:
http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html

Hence your initial intuitive understanding matches more `CombineLatest`
http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/combinelatest.html

To your original question regardless of the included code - assuming a super simplified scenario in which you `Zip` or `CombineLatest` two streams with one emitted value you could achieve something similar in `PromiseKit` with `when(resolved: guarantees).done {`